# Vue - chrome.webstore.install "Cannot read property 'install' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm trying to use the [inline install](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation) on my extension website. The site is made using vue and I'm not able to call the `chrome.webstore.install()`, I get always this error `vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined`

I've two chrome store links and as per documentation I need to pass the link to the extension that will be installed, in my vue template code to do this I've used the `@click.prevent="installExtension(url)"` and in my methods

```
installExtension(url){
 chrome.webstore.install(url, this.onsuccess(), this.onerror() )
}
```

As I wrote I get the error in console and I'm not able to see any popup.
How I can prompt the installation of the extension for firefox and chrome in my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately inline installs were linked to malicious behavior and have been deprecated.

```
Important: As of 06/12/2018, inline installation is deprecated.
```

Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

Google blog post: https://blog.chromium.org/2018/06/improving-extension-transparency-for.html

Comment: So there isn't any alternative to it?

Comment: Linking to the Chrome Web Store is the only option available. I would look at popular websites that have Chrome extensions to find a call to action that works for your use case. From what I can see they tend to use a large button at the center of the homepage that links to their listing in the Web Store.